# Copying 0 as 000 in C++?

Tags: c, string, printf

This question is ANSWERED. Nothing to do with formatters but instead my idiocy when it comes to copying to new buffers.

---

I'm hoping this is a one line answer. I have a `snprintf()` statement which is something like the following:

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%03d", 0U);
```

I'm expecting `buffer` to hold `000` but for some reason it only holds `00`. Assume the buffer is plenty large enough to hold what I want. Am I being silly?

EDIT:

See below for complete code with context. I was trying to simplify it before as I didn't think all this context was necessary. The point still remains, using `%04u` gives me `000` in the first CSV row. `%03u` only gives me `00`.

```
uint16_t CSVGenerator::write_csv_data(TestRecord* record)
{
    // Define the templates.
    const char *row_template = "%04u,%6.3E,%6.3E,%6.3E,%6.3E,%6.3E\n";
    char csv_row_buffer[CSV_ROW_BUFFER_SIZE];

    // Add the data.
    uint16_t row_count = 0U;
   for (uint16_t reading = 0U; reading < MEASURE_READING_COUNT; ++reading)
   {
       // Parse the row.
       snprintf(csv_row_buffer, sizeof(csv_row_buffer), row_template,
               // Test ID
               MEASURE_PERIOD_SECS * reading,
               // Impedances Z1-Z5.
               record->measurements[reading][0U],
               record->measurements[reading][1U],
               record->measurements[reading][2U],
               record->measurements[reading][3U],
               record->measurements[reading][4U]);

       // Add it to the main buffer, excluding the terminator.
       strncpy((m_csv_data_buffer + (reading * CSV_ROW_BUFFER_SIZE) - 1U),
               csv_row_buffer, (sizeof(csv_row_buffer) - 1U));

       // Increment the row count.
       ++row_count;
   } // for : each reading.

   return row_count;
}
```

Comment: How large is buffer, what is it, how is it defined?

Comment: @Mat: Say `char buffer[8U]`.

Comment: Is buffer being defined as `char *buffer = malloc( blah )`; by any chance? Also if your number is unsigned you should use `%03u` (not d)

Comment: @EdKing: in the same function, or is it passed as a parameter? (i.e. please don't make us guess what your code actually is, please post a short, complete snippet that reproduces your issue)

Comment: The code you have works fine when `buffer` is defined correctly: http://codepad.org/FN5O7LHu But Mat asks a very good question; it won't work in a function.

Comment: @Dave: No, I'm not using dynamic memory. Changed to use %u, no effect.

Comment: Change it to "%04u" and see what happens. I'm curious.

Comment: What's the sizeof buffer? Try `printf("sizeof buffer is %d.\n", (int)sizeof(buffer));` right before your snprintf() call.

Comment: What's your environment?

Comment: Please post a complete, compilable example that demonstrates the problem. There's no point in making guesses about code we can't see.

Comment: maybe you are reading back the content of your buffer in the wrong way (via printf?, via debugger?). It's impossible to answer unless you give us the complete code and even the environment (buggy snprintf()?)

Comment: Can't see where you're printing the buffer in your sample code.

Comment: That is neither complete nor compilable code. Post a complete `main` function that fills and prints the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you check that it contains only "000"? If you are reading it from `(m_csv_data_buffer + (reading * CSV_ROW_BUFFER_SIZE))` you are actually losing the first byte since you've copied it to `(m_csv_data_buffer + (reading * CSV_ROW_BUFFER_SIZE) - 1U)` in your code.

Comment: You guys are right. the `csv_row_buffer` has what I want - the `m_csv_data_buffer` has a byte missing.

Answer (score 1):

`strncpy` handles null terminators implicitly so I'm guessing where you're subtracting 1 from the target buffer address you're actually putting the first character of your new row into the last byte of the previous row.

You seem to be using a combination of fixed buffer sizes and variable string lengths. This is what is the likely cause of what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

are you on a 16bit machine? maybe you declared buffer as a char* so sizeof(buffer) evaluates as 2 and snprintf copies only the first two bytes of the actual output "000" (plus the terminator character 0x00)

I suspect the problem resides on *how* you read back the content of your buffer, not the actual content, maybe the:

```
Some dummy code to keep buffer in scope while I check it..
```

is way more important than what you posted

Comment: If `sizeof(char*)` were 2, only one `'0'` would be written, the count for `snprintf` includes the 0-terminator.

Comment: you're right, only one '0'